# Masking tooltip of a Text field

Tags: swt

I need to hide tooltip for a password Text field. Please suggest.
I have something like below and getToolTipText() needs to return blank or hidden text, because original password getting rendered in UI.

```java
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text text = new org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text(parent, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.PASSWORD);
```

Comment: The tooltip of a `Text` control does not show the control's contents unless you have written code to make it do so.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. I have not written any code to do so.

Comment: If you have not written any code for the tooltip then it should be empty. Tell us **exactly** what you are seeing.

Comment: I am seeing the original password text as tooltip.

Comment: I can't reproduce this

Answer (score 0):

It should not show you tooltip when you use "SWT.PASSWORD". It doesn't show tooltip for me.
Can you post more of your code with the text control.
Anyway if you want you can always set empty toolbox with

```
textControl.setToolTipText("");
```

but this is not necessary and it should be done without this.